# How to implement Master/Detail Flow?

Tags: android, master-detail

[image]

I want to show this type of menu, when i clicked any item of menu, description of that item is shown in right panel. This menu always available on screen.

Which type of widget i have to use for this.

Comment: You can search for navigation drawer, side menu this items disappears when you click. For not disappearing you can use fragments

Comment: You project create with menu  in Android Studio step : New->project->click Next Til add Activity to project  page and select "Navigation Drawer Activity"

Comment: Its not a navigation drawer. Look for master flow detail here- https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/descendant.html#master-detail

Comment: Thanks for understanding my question.. @onexf ... Everybody on this site always in hurry , nobody wants to understand the question,  only what they want is disliking the question.

Comment: I implement master flow detail, but when i click on any item, it switch to the  another activity, but I want when i click to the item , description shows in right panel, instead of switching activity. Please help me for this .. @onexf

Comment: can you post your code along with the q?

Answer (score 0):

Try this library : [MaterialDrawer](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer)

There is no need to do anything with xml files and it all done with code.

Answer (score 0):

By using a Master/Detail flow template, in a small screen which does not have enough space to continue both the Master and Detail pages, a different Activity page is used for each but in large screen with landscape orientation, both the Master and Detail pages are combined in a single Activity page.  Select this when starting a new project.

[image]

If you're doing it with an existing project, check this https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SAPDocuments/Tutorials/master/tutorials/hcpdo-basic-android-app/mg6-2-04.png